# While loop inside async function executes one extra time when condition is false

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, electron

I'm using Electron to package an R Shiny app. It works fine in my computer and in most computers I've tested. However, in some cases it crashed (usually in slower computers). I'm not familiar with Javascript and I'm trying to understand what is happening in the JS code I'm using.

After a while trying to figue out what caused the crash, I noticed that a while loop that should be executed **only when my app hasn't been shown yet**, is actually executed one more time. I suspect this may be causing the problem (although I'm not sure). The following is what I run when the electron app is ready.

```js
app.on('ready', async () => {
  let shinyRunning = false
  let i = 1

  loadingSplashScreen = createSplashScreen('loading')
  mainWindow = createWindow()

  try {
    rShinyProcess = execa(NODER,
      ['-e', 'rbingo::launch_app(options = list(port = ' + srv.address().port + '))'], {
      env: {
        // Necessary for letting R know where it is and ensure we're not using another R
        'WITHIN_ELECTRON': 'T', // can be used within an app to implement specific behaviour
        'RHOME': rResources,
        'R_HOME_DIR': rResources,
        'R_LIBS': path.join(rResources, "library"),
        'R_LIBS_USER': path.join(rResources, "library"),
        'R_LIBS_SITE': path.join(rResources, "library"),
        'R_LIB_PATHS': path.join(rResources, "library")
        }
      })
    } catch {
       console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ':rshinyprocess execa catched')
       console.log(e)
    }
    
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:' + srv.address().port);
    
    try {
        while(!shinyRunning) {
            const wait_res = await waitFor(1000);
            console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': Trying to connect...' + i)
            i += 1
            console.log('shinyRunning status: ' + shinyRunning)
            
            mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('window.Shiny.shinyapp.isConnected()', true)
              .then((result) => {
                    shinyRunning = true
                    mainWindow.show()
                    loadingSplashScreen.hide()
                    loadingSplashScreen.close()
                    console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': Successfully connected to the app')
            })
              .catch((result) => {
            })
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': Error catched while trying to load the app.')
    }

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': mainWindow.closed()')
        cleanUpApplication()
    })

    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-fail-load', (event, code, desc, url, isMainFrame) => {
      console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': DID FAIL LOAD - ', code, desc, url, isMainFrame);
    });
})
```

```
23:56:38.475 > Application Started
2020-11-06T02:56:38.489Z: Listening on port 49271
2020-11-06T02:56:39.593Z: Trying to connect...1
shinyRunning status: false
2020-11-06T02:56:40.594Z: Trying to connect...2
shinyRunning status: false
2020-11-06T02:56:41.594Z: Trying to connect...3
shinyRunning status: false
2020-11-06T02:56:42.594Z: Trying to connect...4
shinyRunning status: false
2020-11-06T02:56:42.949Z: Successfully connected to the app 
2020-11-06T02:56:43.594Z: Trying to connect...5             <------ THIS SHOULDN'T BE HERE
shinyRunning status: true                                   <------ THIS SHOULDN'T BE HERE
```

**My question is:** What is causing this while loop to be executed one extra time when `shinyRunning` is `true`?

If you need more info about my app or the entire .js file, I can share it too.

Thanks,
Tomas

**PS:** `waitFor` is just

```js
function waitFor(miliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, miliseconds);
  });
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @cuspymd for the answer and @syarul for the comment.

I've updated the code, now I'm not using a while loop anymore, and the console looks better.

```js
...

    mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:' + srv.address().port);
    
    try {
        await mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('window.Shiny.shinyapp.isConnected()', true)
            .then((result) => {
                mainWindow.show()
                loadingSplashScreen.hide()
                loadingSplashScreen.close()
                console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': Successfully connected to the app')
                shinyRunning = true
        })
            .catch((result) => {
        })  
        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': Error catched while trying to load the app.')
    }

...
```

```
11:02:51.653 > Application Started
2020-11-06T14:02:51.668Z: Listening on port 63065
2020-11-06T14:02:56.079Z: Successfully connected to the app
```

Comment: This weird, why do you put async function inside while loop?, I've seen a lot questions like this all over the place in stackoverflow [javascript]. This is very bad code practice putting asynchronous code inside a synchronous loop code

Comment: I'm very beginner with JS. This is code I've copied and pasted. I've updated my code with what @cuspymd suggested and it works better now I think. I've also  deleted the while loop. Is that similar to how you would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `await` to wait for the result of executing `window.Shiny.shinyapp.isConnected()`.

```
...
            await mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('window.Shiny.shinyapp.isConnected()', true)
              .then((result) => {
                    shinyRunning = true
                    mainWindow.show()
                    loadingSplashScreen.hide()
                    loadingSplashScreen.close()
                    console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': Successfully connected to the app')
            })
...
```

Comment: Now the while is executed only once, but the app loads and it is not executed anymore. Thank you!